# Is there a way we can use an image as a stroke or fill style like we can with gradients?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Using a gradient instead of a color to draw on Canvas is easy:

```
let gradient0 = ctx.createLinearGradient(x, topY, x, bottomY)
// add color stops
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient0;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

I'm hoping there's a feature in HTML5 Canvas to do this easily so I dont have to go writing shaders for it. Googling it didnt turn anything up. So is there a way we can use an image as a stroke or fill style like we can with gradients?

Comment: "we know canvas is using a webgl shader to apply the correct color" - 2D canvas contexts are completely independent of WebGL - nor does it have to be using a shader program to implement.

Comment: @J Todd I think you have a misunderstanding of how graphics works in general. No, WebGL is the name of the interface available in-browser, browsers themselves won't be proxying WebGL via Canvas2D; furthermore WebGL is concerned with 3D scenes, not 2D drawing. MSHTML (IE11 and older) did its page drawing through an unholy mix of Direct2D, GDI, and Direct3D - it didn't use OpenGL. IE11's WebGL was a proxy in-front of Direct3D and I believe its Canvas2D implementation was using Direct2D. Firefox uses Cairo, etc.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the education, I removed my misguided info in the question.

Comment: @Dai Yeah I did misunderstand. I had the idea that WebGL would be the interfaced used for all aspects of canvas. Ive used webgl shaders for 2D graphics processing plenty, I mean there's plenty use for shader code with 2D graphics. I contributed a bit to [GPU.js](https://gpu.rocks/#/) which made it easy to do 2D shader code without much knowledge of what's going on beyond webgl.

Answer (score 3):

> Googling it didnt turn anything up.

If you googled [the `strokeStyle` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeStyle) you'ld see that [you can use a `CanvasPattern` object to use an Image for a Stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern):

```
const imageSource = /* must be a DOM "Image-like" object, e.g. HTMLImageElement, SVGElement, HTMLVideoElement, HTMLCanvasElemment, Blob, ImageData - or another existing ImageBitmap which will be cloned */;

// * See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#dom-createimagebitmap-dev
// * `createImageBitmap` returns a Promise<ImageBitmap> so you must await it before you can use it with `createPattern`.
const sourceImage = await ctx.createImageBitmap( imageSource ); // : ImageBitmap

// Cache this pattern somewhere so you don't recreate it every time you stroke a single path - otherwise that would be very silly.
const pattern = ctx.createPattern( sourceImage, 'repeat-x' ); // : CanvasPattern

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo( x, topY    );
ctx.lineTo( x, bottomY );
ctx.lineWidth   = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

Note that if you use an `OffscreenCanvas` instead of an `ImageBitmap` for the [`sourceImage` used by `createPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern) then you can apply arbitrary transformations (e.g. affine transformations) to the `sourceImage` if you want to scale, rotate, change colours, etc of the image being used as the pattern.

Apparently the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern` function also accepts other "`Image`-like" objects, just like `createImageBitmap` does, though I'm unsure how that affects performance (it is interesting that `createImageBitmap` returns a `Promise` but `createPattern` does not).

Comment: Update: `createImageBitmap` is an API available on the global context, also it returns a promise. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap#examples